# Rspec test shouldn't fail using own helper method, why does it? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a model test which checks if no string is entered, a default value is stored in the db, 'pending'. I created it in the migration so a default value is entered. It works because in the Rails console when I create a new class instance the value is there. My test however keeps failing with this error

```
Failure/Error: expect(@instance.send(method)).to eq(default)

       expected: "pending"
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Here is the Rspec test

```
RSpec.describe Photo, :type => :model do
  setup_factories

  before do
    @instance=photo
  end

  mandatory_string :firstname
  mandatory_string :lastname
  mandatory_string :email 
  # processes_attachment_to_attribute :attachment
  boolean_default_false :optin 
  optional_string   :phone
    mandatory_string_with_default :workflow_state, 'pending'
```

this is my helper method that defines 'mandatory_string_with_default'

```
  def mandatory_string_with_default(method,default)
    context "#{method} is a mandatory string which defaults to #{default}" do
      it "should set a blank string to #{default}" do
        @instance.send("#{method}=",nil)
        expect(@instance).to be_valid
        expect(@instance.send(method)).to eq(default)
      end
    end
  end
```

here is my factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :photo do
    firstname "MyString"
    lastname "MyString"
    email 
    optin false
    phone "2345345"
    workflow_state "pending"
  end
end
```

and the migration

```
create_table :photos do |t|
  t.string :firstname
  t.string :lastname
  t.string :email
  t.string :attachment
  t.boolean :optin, default: false
  t.string :phone
  t.string :workflow_state, default: 'pending'
  t.timestamps
end
```

why is this test failing? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's failing because you set the field to nil here

```
@instance.send("#{method}=",nil)
```

The `default: 'pending'` in your migration assign the value on creation of the new object, but if you overwrite it then it takes your new value, see by your self

```
photo = Photo.new
photo.workflow_state
=> 'pending'
photo.workflow_state = nil
photo.workflow_state
=> nil
```

---

If you need a substitution of a blank value to 'default' you must manually implement it like this:

```
class Photo

  def workflow_state
    if self[:workflow_state].blank? 
      'default' 
    else
      self[:workflow_state]
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: but i am passing through the correct arguments to the method no?

  1) Photo workflow_state is a mandatory string which defaults to pending should set a blank string to pending

Comment: Nop, what I was trying to explain is: the default value comes when you create the object (with `Photo.new`). After that there is no more default, in other words: it does not substitute a blank value to the default you set in your migration

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, helpful answer. Sometimes the logic throws me.